# button scroll multiple spinners when I want it to scroll only one

Tags: button, javafx, spinner, scenebuilder, actionevent

```
public class ManageSpinners implements Initializable {

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
lettersValueFactory = new 
SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory<String>
(lettersValuesObservList);
lettersValueFactory.setValue("A");
charValueFactory = new 
SpinnerValueFactory.ListSpinnerValueFactory<String>
(charValuesObservList);
charValueFactory.setValue("!");

 spinOne=new Spinner(lettersValueFactory)
 spinOneEditor = spinOne.getEditor();
 spinOne.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, 
  Object newValue) {
      spinOneEditor.setText(spinOne.getValue().toString());
      spinOneEditor.commitValue();
     }
  });

  spinTwo=new Spinner(charValueFactory);
  spinTwoEditor = spinTwo.getEditor();
  spinTwo.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, 
   Object newValue) {
     spinTwoEditor.setText(spinTwo.getValue().toString());
     spinTwoEditor.commitValue();
   }
 });

  buttonOne.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    spinOne.increment();
    }
  });

  buttonTwo.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    spinTwo.increment();
    }
  });
 }
}
```

When I press buttonOne...both Spinners increment,when only spinOne should  increment(as per the code); and same when press buttonTwo,both spinners increment . I want one button control one spinner only.
Where is the mistake ?

Comment: Are the spinners bound to the same value, or otherwise connected? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I have added more details to my question. Thanks

Comment: Create a [MCVE] and post it in your question.